# html/js Layer handling: Create new elements or move and reinitialize

Tags: javascript, html, layer

I often build applications with ajax and many layers (to create/edit/delete different kind of content for example - or show message boxes or something). Some of this layers are much complex in html an js. but i keep asking my self whats the best way to handle the layer elements.

Sometimes i have a template and use cloneNode and sometimes i create the html structure with js (createElement) - depends on complexity. But what's the best way to close the layer?

- move it to a hidden area/hide the layer and show again for reuse: it exists always only one layer but it's much work reinitialize the layer to clear all user input.
- remove the layer elements and create new: less source of error by defined state for initialization but i don't know how the browser handels deleted elements in terms of performance and memory.

i've often build it in both ways but i never seen advantages or disadvantages in practice. So what's the best practice?

Comment: I think this is a better question for a different community, could be too opinionated for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is getting too massive, an `<iframe>` could be a viable solution depending on your application.